# Showing an AlertDialogFragment causes NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

So I'm writing a game called rock, paper, scissors and I get a NullPointerException whenever I'm trying to prompt a user about difficulty. My intention is to launch a new activity passing the difficulty value via intent's putExtra method. This action is to be performed through a custom Dialog. Here is the log:

```
08-11 13:38:09.619    8725-8725/dserov.rockpaperscissors E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: dserov.rockpaperscissors, PID: 8725
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
        at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
        at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Bind(R.id.singleplayerButton) Button mSingleplayerButton;
@Bind(R.id.multiplayerButton) Button mMultiplayerButton;
@Bind(R.id.gameEmblem) ImageView mGameEmblem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case (R.id.singleplayerButton) : {
                    AlertDialogFragment dialog = new AlertDialogFragment();
                    dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.difficulty_dialog));
                    break;
                }

                case (R.id.multiplayerButton) : {
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    };

    mSingleplayerButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
    mMultiplayerButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Here is AlertDialogFragment:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = getActivity();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.difficulty_prompt)
            .setItems(R.array.difficulties, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PlayActivity.class);
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0 : {
                            intent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.difficulty_label), 0);
                            break;
                        }
                        case 1 : {
                            intent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.difficulty_label), 1);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
    }
}
```

Android Studio's bugtracker function does not give any results, the exception is thrown via some system function whenever the Singleplayer button is pressed. There are no clues as of after which line of code I get the exception, but my best guess would be the show() method of AlertDialogFragment.

Comment: Can you post R.array.difficulties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to figure it all night long and I finally understand what the mistake was. Changing `.setItems(R.array.difficulties ...` to `.setItems(context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.difficulties) ...` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

when does it crush? in your code I didn't see you a line where you dismiss the dialog so if you don't have that line and the app crushes after the dialog is showing and before you are redirected to another activity try dismissing the dialog